# Driver not found exception while querying oracle using spark submit in yarn-client mode

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-sql

I am getting the following exception while submitting job to spark:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: 
    No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pass@x.x.x.x:1521:orcl
```

Command used to submit job:

```
bin/spark-submit --class com.mycompany.app.App 
--master yarn-client 
--conf spark.yarn.jar=hdfs://192.168.xxx.xx:9000/spark-assembly-1.3.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar 
--driver-class-path hdfs://192.168.xxx.xx:9000/ojdbc7.jar 
--jars hdfs://192.168.xxx.xx:9000/ojdbc7.jar  
/home/impadmin/maventest-idw/my-app/target/my-app-1.0.jar
```

Any pointers?

Comment: The issue was resolved by providing the driver path of the remote machine

Answer (score 1):

--jar does not need to be used if you are using it with HDFS, HTTP or FTP files.

You can directly use SparkContext.addJar("path of jar file")